# AppleScripts Help...Close all Open Windows in Evernote

Tags: applescript, automation, evernote

I want to set up automation to close all open windows in Evernote every time the number of open windows exceeds 10.

- Application: Evernote
- Test: Windows Open > 10
- Action: Close all Open Windows

EverNote does have a "Close All Note Windows" command.

[image]

Comment: I should have led with...

Hi all! I'm Leo. I'm excited about being part of the community! Please don't hesitate to ask for my help with anything.

Comment: No you should not have this site is for questions and answers. Think of writing  it as s a reference  book you can find things I in a few years

Comment: 1. I imagine you could run a background AppleScript sleeping every x seconds. 2. On idle, check if Evernote is the active app. You need this to access the menu you described. 3. Count the number of windows. 4. If Evernote is the active app, trigger the menu using System Events. Note: I don't have Evernote.